# Can't see my demo application with the Titanium android emulator

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I try to run a simple demo titanium application(as described in the tutorial: [pizza app](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/appcelerator/titanium-mobile-build-a-pizza-ordering-app/)) with the titanium emulator, but all I can see is just the android default screen:

[android home http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/7084/titaniumbug.png](http://img545.imageshack.us/img545/7084/titaniumbug.png)

How can I see my application?

p.s. I don't see any "red errors" in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Titanium Studio doesn't run the app once it's installed.
it sais in the end of installation.

> [INFO] Application installed. Launch from drawer on Home Screen

you can see the app if you press on the middle button on the desktop and then looking for your app and running it

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. I tried to find my application in the applications list, but I just couldn't. Anyway, I don't see the line: [INFO] Application installed. Launch from drawer on Home Screen

Comment: @benams, look here for more reference: [https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Quick+Start](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Quick+Start)

Comment: I know this guide and I've already read it. The answer isn't there. Thanks anyway...

Comment: if you don't see the line above. there's a problem in your application